# Can we convert Mvc Application developed .Net framework to Mvc Asp.Net Core 2.0 without code change or minimal code change

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have developed my application in Mvc 5.2.3 using .net Framework.
now  i need to convert my application to Asp.net Mvc Core 2.0.

Can i convert it without code change or minimal code change or i have to migrate while code ?

Comment: Start from reading [Migration to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration) section to understand what is the general/minimal steps needed to do a migration to ASP.NET Core

Comment: it is useful thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to convert from Asp.Net from .NetFramework to Asp.Net Core
You can find the details at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

To answer as to how big a change would be required will depend on your project's complexity. There are certain libraries/classes which are not supported or certain behavioral changes in Asp.Net Core. You might have to figure out the right replacements for them in Asp.Net Core.